# How to use external function .js file in Protractor

Tags: protractor, external

I have some repeating functions and I want to isolate them in another file for use in Protractor. I don't want to have them in the same file as the tests are. How would I do this? I run protractor against an external non-angular web site, like this:

```
protractor conf.js
```

So inside spec.js I have these kinds of functions that I simply want to reuse:

```
function someFunction() {
    console.log("We are in a function");
}
```

How can I put them aside in another .js file or something similar? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my-module.js

```
module.exports = {
    custom_function: function() {
        console.log("whatever")
    }
};
```

spec.js

```
const custom_function = (require("./my-module.js")).custom_function;

describe("Suite: UCare - Provider Search - 'Places' tab", () => {

    it("1", async () => {
        custom_function();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out already in the meanwhile, by accident, but this is correct answer too.

Answer (score 0):

well you could create another file and put whatever functions you'd like inside then export the module

```
module.exports = {
    someFunctions: {

        someFunction: () => {
            console.log("We are in a function");
        };

    }
}
```

"Import" it in your spec file:

```
const functionsPageObject = require('../your/path/functionsFile');
```

Then use them:

```
functionsPageObject.someFunctions.someFunction();
```